# LocalDateTime via Scannerinput

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, java-time

I need to insert a `LocalDateTime` from a `Scanner`.
We are required to use the input format

```
dd.MM. HH:mm
```

for the `Scanner` (without using extra variables!), how can I get these scanned values into the start variable?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Year:");
int year = sc.nextInt(); 

System.out.println("Start:");
//--- (?) scan something like dd.MM. HH:mm --- 
start = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute)
```

If the scanned input is not in the format `dd.MM. HH:mm`, the program is supposed to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. I know how THAT works, just so you know we can't use `sc.next()` and the `getsubstring()` :(

Comment: Read the date as a single `String`, parse it with an appropriate formatter using [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-), catch `DateTimeParseException` and rethrow it as `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: I tried this, but the scanner seems to scan only until I press the space bar in between MM. and HH: and then it stops

Comment: What space bar? The format you gave has no whitespaces.

Comment: yes it has - in between MM and HH ! The specified format is supposed to be EXACTLY like "dd.MM. HH.mm" :(

Comment: Ah! My bad, the line break was exactly on the space. I edited it to show more clearly.

Comment: I'm guessing the point of this exercise is to make you acquainted with reading the Scanner class' [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). There are more methods than `next()`. Can you find one that e.g. returns the whole input line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner` allows you to specify a pattern to which the input will be matched. If a match was successful, you can query it. This is the basic idea:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Year:");
        int year = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Date-time in format: dd.MM. HH:mm");
        sc.nextLine();
        sc.findInLine("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\. (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
        try {
            MatchResult mr = sc.match();
            int month = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1));
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(3));
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(4));
            LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);
            System.out.println(dt);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid date-time format.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can use named groups instead of referring to the numbers if you want something more fancy. You can also add additional constraints on the input so it will be a legitimate date-time format, but `LocalDateTime.of` will take care of that anyway, which brings me to...

**Note about exception handling:** in this case an `IllegalStateException` is thrown if the pattern is not matched, as requested. However, the same exception will be thrown by `LocalDateTime.of` if the numbers given in the (valid) format make no sense, like `90` for month. You will probably want to catch the `DateTimeException` separately.

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what I was looking for !